# How to run crontab-e?

Tags: php, cron

I am currently reading this documentation [here](http://corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/) where I want to use CRON. Now it says in the first section that I need to enter in a command: `crontab -e`.

Do I only need to enter this in a simple text editor file and just upload the file into the server?

I am using helios.hud.ac.uk so would this be the correct command:

```
* * 25 10 * helios.hud.ac.uk/u00000000/Mobile/inactivatesession.php
```

This will execute this php script below (inactivatesession.php):

```
<?php

include('connect.php');


$createDate = mktime(0,0,0,10,25,date("Y"));
$selectedDate =  date('d-m-Y', ($createDate));

$sql = "UPDATE Session SET Active = ? WHERE DATE_FORMAT(SessionDate,'%Y-%m-%d' ) <= ?";                                         
$update = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$update->bind_param("is", 0, $selectedDate);
$update->execute();

?>
```

The url for this php script is: helios.hud.ac.uk/u00000000/Mobile/inactivatesession.php

I havn't used CRON before so just need little help on it.

Thanks

Comment: You type it on a command line. If they don't give you access to a command line (usually through ssh) you probably don't have access to cron.

Comment: there are other options if you don't have shall access, ask your sys admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You open a shell (probably through SSH) to your server
2. You run the command `crontab -e`
3. You edit the crontab according to your needs (if you want to run a php script over http you need to use `wget`)
4. You save and exit If you didn't make any mistakes, you will get a message that crontab was updated

Comment: Ok it is just opening the shell I don't quite understand. I use filezilla to connect to helios server, Im guessing that has nothing to do with it. Do I access the shell by typing in something in the url?

Comment: Nope, are you on a shared hosting?

Comment: You can't do this through FTP and most probably you are on a shared host which means you can't do it. Ask your hosting provider how he can provide you with cronjob setup.

Comment: Yes I'm on shared hosting with other students. In the url `u0000000` is my id so when I access the host `helios.hud.ac.uk`, to go to my section I type in my id

Comment: As I said, you don't have shell access which means you can't edit your crontab. Ask your host.

Comment: Ok so if I ask the admin to setup a cronjob, do I email him this `* * 25 10 * wget -O - http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u00000000/Mobile/inactivatesession.php` so then he can set up the cron for me?

Comment: I guess that might be possible, depends on your host.

Comment: OK, thank you for your information and help :) hopefully the host will do it for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are making a crontab that will access a remote webpage (which is what this is as it is not on your local server) you need to prepend the URL with `wget`

```
* * 25 10 * wget -O - http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u00000000/Mobile/inactivatesession.php
```

It will run the script on the server and output it to standard output (which in most servers will be emailed to you)

This assumes that you have a linux machine.  `crontab -e` sets up a cron tab for your user account.  So you can't really upload a crontab, but if you have cpanel or similar, most times you have access to cron from there.